# Error when modifying UIViewController to UIcollectionViewContorller in ViewController? [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift

It seems that I lack the basics of swift, so I am studying from the beginning while watching YouTube.

**youtube example** : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vI7m5RTYNng

At `5:40~7:40 seconds` of the video, I get an error in `class ViewController: UIViewController` where I change `UIViewController` to `UIcollectionViewContorller`,
But there is an error. There is an error in the video. I looked at it and followed the video exactly, but in the video the error was resolved and I did not. I think the code is the same, why doesn't the error get resolved?

**Error name**

[UICollectionViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "UIViewController-BYZ-38-t0r" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UICollectionView.'

I thought it was an error because I didn't create anything on the storyboard, but there was nothing on the storyboard in the video.

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .yellow
    }
}
```

**AppDelegate**

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        window?.rootViewController = ViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

I searched hard, but I don't understand well because I lack basic knowledge about swift.
Thank you

Comment: Check if in storyboard there is any viewController or not? if YES, then delete it and then add new UICollectionViewcontroller and assign ViewController class to it.

Comment: Do you also have a SceneDelegate.swift file?

Comment: Thank you Saurabh Prajapati One more thing I'm curious about, but in the video, the ```viewcontroller``` doesn't touch anything in the ```storyboard```, but he created a ```uicollectionViewController``` before starting the video and started it?

Comment: Sweeper-Yes, but in the video there is nothing to touch because the SceneDelegate.swift file is not used.

Comment: @je2 Note that there isn't even a SceneDelegate in the video. The video is outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using Xcode 11+. The video is kind of outdated now, as it's using Xcode 10 or before. Since Xcode 11, the App project template will create a SceneDelegate.swift for you. You should set the rootVC of the window in the SceneDelegate instead:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        window?.rootViewController = ViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    }
    ...
```

Here, the `window` variable will be assigned by UIKit the actual `UIWindow` instance. On the other hand, the `window` in AppDelegate.swift, which you probably declared yourself (after Xcode 11 they moved the `window` property from AppDelegate to SceneDelegate), doesn't get this special treatment.